# How to convert big number to string value in JavaScript without using any external lib?

Tags: javascript

[Convert the ASCII value sentence to its equivalent string](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-the-ascii-value-sentence-to-its-equivalent-string/)

This is for writing a similar program given above. I tried to convert the input directly to string value for the iteration. 
What is happening is, assume the input value is

```
var num = 23511011501782351112179911801562340161171141148;
```

When I convert this number to string

```
num.toString()
```

I'm getting the result like this:

> "2.351101150178235e+46"

There are so many similar questions asked in SOF, but I didn't see any proper answers.

Can someone help me with how to iterate each value in the input? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where the input from? Is it possible to get as string?

Comment: `var num = 23511011501782351112179911801562340161171141148n; console.log(num.toString());` fascinatingly complex.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you mean correctly, you can replace the code `char ch = (char)num;` with `var ch = String.fromCharCode(num);`. Like this:

```js
var result = [];

function asciiToSentence(str, len) 
{ 
    var num = 0; 
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) { 
  
        // Append the current digit 
        num = num * 10 + (str[i] - '0'); 
  
        // If num is within the required range 
        if (num >= 32 && num <= 122) { 
  
            // Convert num to char 
            var ch = String.fromCharCode(num); 
            
            result.push(ch)
  
            // Reset num to 0 
            num = 0; 
        } 
    } 
} 

var str = "7110110110711510211111471101101107115"; 
var len = str.length; 
asciiToSentence(str, len); 

console.log(result.join(''));
```

Reference: [String.fromCharCode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)

---

Explanation:

First, inside the function `asciiToSentence`, we need 2 parameters `str` and `len` (`str` is a string while `len` is the length of that string).

Next, we make a temporary `num` to calculate the number inside the string based on this table: [ASCII Printable Characters](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ascii.asp)

We trying to parse one-by-one character to a number and multiply it with 10. Then, we compare it between 32 and 122 (based on the number in the table above).

If the number we have is inside the range, we parse that number to a character using `String.fromCharCode` function and reset the value `num`. Otherwise, we continue the loop and increase the value `num`

Comment: You didn't explain the conversion part in the above program. how to get exact string value from the input    var num = 7110110110711510211111471101101107115; ?

Comment: @SarunUK I'm sorry, there are too many messages in my notification list, so I'm lost your comment message. I've updated my answer with explanation.